# What is the colour of a yellow flower which is kept in sunlight watched through a red filter paper?

Tags: visible-light

Which will be the colour of the flower;  can you  see through it finally?

Answer (score 1):

If you had a filter that only let though light of 700nm wavelength (red light), then the only colors you could see would be red or black. A yellow flower probably doesn't reflect light perfectly in only a narrow yellow band, so there will be some red light to be seen, so the flower would appear red, albeit possibly very dark red.

However, unless you're getting high-end equipment, your filter probably doesn't block all non-red light. So you will see the flower as being more reddish than normal, but not completely red. What color exactly you see depends on how yellow the flower is and how red the filer is.

Another factor, however, is that the brain automatically does color balancing (the infamous "what color is the dress" meme is an example of this). So if you see a field of more-reddish-than-usual things, and one of those things is a flower than is normally yellow, your brain will subtract out some, if not all, of the extra red and perceive it as more yellow than the light reaching your eyes actually is.